# How to localize my Vue components library?

Tags: vue.js, localization, vue-component, vue-i18n

I develop my own vue components library, and this components have a lot of texts that needs to be localized. **vue-i18n** doesn't support this, because it should be attached to **Vue** (e.g. `Vue.use(VueI18n)`), but in case of component library, it will result in conflict.

I need to have independent translation files in my library, totally separated from my application (to prevent conflicts)

I'm struggling to find any answer to this question in other sources, and I hope someone can give me example for this case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know Element UI has i18n capabilities, maybe you can get inspiration from their source code? https://github.com/ElemeFE/element

Comment: Valentin, thank you. I see they use old version of vue-i18n, but it still unclear for me how to do it with new version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it really seems that vue-i18n is not tailored for use in component libraries for reasons you are mentioning (attaching itself into `Vue.prototype` + conflict with user's code).

I don't know what features of vue-i18n are you using but if it's just simple translation, it seems rolling your own custom solution with an option to plug in the i18n library of user's choice would be the best. It's not that hard. Most of the component libraries are going that way...

You can take a look at how "big guys" do it - in this case Vuetify. 
[Docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/internationalization)
[Code](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/services/lang/index.ts)

Comment: Thank you for detailed reply and provided links. I will take a look inside vuetify and element one more time. There is open issue for vue-i18n: https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/746.

Another option is implementing my own library, and I also need it for templates on backend. Maybe there are existing solutions without dependency of vue and runtime-agnostic, so I can use them in lib and server-side templates for email. I will check out for other solution from this point of view, thank you for hinting it.

Comment: You are right that maybe choosing different library which doesn't tight itself into Vue can be solution too. There is for example [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/) - its mature and can be used on many backends too. I didn't proposed it as a solution because of my background in .NET where using library from a library means your users are attached to the version of lib you are using. But in JS it's probably not that big problem....

Comment: nearly 4 years later and this is still the best approach. The link to the code is broken, anyone looking for it, it's probably this one now:
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/composables/locale.ts